# get reason why ajax request failed

Tags: jquery

I have this ajax request:

```
$.get("https://domain.de/ajax.php").done(function (response) {
    // DO SOMETHING                 
}).fail(function() {
   // ERROR
})
```

How can I get the reason, why the request failed?

Comment: `.fail((err) => {})` - `err` param gives you the failing reason, basically you need a param added to your `.fail` callback function.

Comment: @NicolaeMaties – The error param is the third one, not the first one.

Comment: @Quentin Thought it's the first, haven't verified the docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> ```
> jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});
> ```

The third argument to the callback function you pass to `fail` will give you the error that was thrown.

Note that, for security reasons, the details of many errors are concealed from JavaScript (e.g. cross-origin errors) but these will be displayed in the browser's developer tools console automatically.